# split an already split array string in Java

Tags: java, arrays, split

I have a csv that has been read and split in 3 different csvs. The csv was pipe separated and the split variable is saved in a string variable. I want to split the new string as comma separated string but as soon as I do that, it gives an exception.`

```
try(BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(newcsvCategory))){
    String line;
    while ((line = br1.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] value1 = line.split("\\|,",-1);
        String Id = value1[0];
        String CatId=value1[1];
```

```
["Active Catalog Detail (Network Id "|" Category Ids "]
["209"|"4900,10368,11093,11581,10082,10206,10431,10119,11622,10358,11094,2,10342,5193,10738,11744,10039,10840,5132,10011,11132,5233,10792"]
["174"|"4900,10082,10119,10358,10039,5132,10011"]
["200"|"4900,10368,11093,11581,10082,10206,10431,10119,11622,10358,11094,2,5193,10738,11623,10039,10840,5132,10011,11132,5233,10792"]
["181"|"4900,10358,10011"]
["240"|"4900,10368,11093,11581,10082,10206,10431,10119,11622,10358,11094,2,10342,5193,10738,11744,10039,10840,5132,10011,11132,5233,10792"]
["206"|"4900,10368,11093,11581,10082,10206,10431,10119,11622,10358,11094,2,5193,10738,11623,10039,10840,5132,10011,11132,5233,10792"]
["255"|"4900,10368,11093,11581,10082,10206,11621,10431,10119,11622,10358,11094,2,10342,5193,10738,11744,10039,10840,5132,10011,11132,5233,10792"]
["251"|"4900,10368,11093,11581,10082,10206,11621,10431,10119,11622,10358,11094,2,10342,5193,10738,11744,10039,10840,5132,10011,11132,5233,10792"]
["231"|"4900,10368,11093,11581,10082,10206,10431,10119,11622,10358,11094,2,10342,5193,10738,11744,10039,10840,5132,10011,11132,5233,10792"]
["179"|"4900,10368,11618,11093,11581,10082,10206,10431,10119,11622,10358,11094,2,5193,10738,11623,10039,10840,5132,10011,11132,5233,10792"]
["184"|"4900,10368,11093,11581,10082,10206,10431,10119,11622,10358,11094,2,5193,10738,11623,10039,10840,5132,10011,11132,5233,10792"]
["187"|"4900,10368,11093,11581,10082,10206,10431,10119,11622,10358,11094,2,5193,10738,11623,10039,10840,5132,10011,11132,5233,10792"]
["247"|"4900,10368,11093,11581,10082,10206,11621,10431,10119,11622,10358,11094,2,10342,5193,10738,11744,10039,10840,5132,10011,11132,5233,10792"]
["215"|"10358"]
["216"|"4900,10368,11093,11581,10082,10206,10431,10119,11622,10358,11094,2,10342,5193,10738,11744,10039,10840,5132,10011,11132,5233,10792"]
["238"|"4900,10368,11093,11581,10082,10206,10431,10119,11622,10358,11094,2,10342,5193,10738,11744,10039,10840,5132,10011,11132,5233,10792"]
["224"|"4900,10368,11093,11581,10082,10206,10431,10119,11622,10358,11094,2,10342,5193,10738,11744,10039,10840,5132,10011,11132,5233,10792"]
```

I want split the first column and second column as pipe separated and then further separate the second column as comma separated.

I'd appreciate any help as I'm a newbie.

added code that is splitting CatId:

```
String[] temp = CatId.split(",",-1);
System.out.println(temp[1]);
```

Comment: Can you include the exception in your question by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52968918/edit) your question?

Answer (score 1):

Really, can't realise the questions, but give some notes.

```
// this source string: serveral columsn with different separators
String str = "209|4900,10368,11093,11581";
```

According to your code, you try to put all separate number into string array, with two steps:

```
String[] arr = str.split("\\|");    // not line.split("\\|,",-1)
// arr[0] = 209
// arr[1] = [4900,10368,11093,11581]
String[] tmp = arr[1].split(",")
// tmp[0] = 4900
// tmp[1] = 10368
// tmp[2] = 11093
// tmp[3] = 11581
```

If so, you can do it with one step:

```
String[] arr = str.split("[\\|,]");
// arr[0] = 209
// arr[1] = 4900
// arr[2] = 10368
// arr[3] = 11093
// arr[4] = 11581
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to set the Limit of .split(..) to 2.

```
 while ((line = br1.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] value1 = line.split("\\|",2);
    String Id = value1[0];
    String CatId=value1[1]
};
```

To further split the contet of "CatId" use:

```
// if you need to replace unwanted chars first, you could just use the simple .replace:
CatId = CatId.replace("\"", "").replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
// Then, split the array just by ,
String[] catIdArray = CatId.split("\\,");
```

Comment: Okay, somehow i get the value in value1[1]. i want to apply split basesd on "," on value1[1] but it gives exception.

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1